# How to recover in a template a value from the database in django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I wish I could retrieve in the form of my template the answer to my question (if there is one)

> My models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

**How can I access with my model since the answers of my questions?**

> My template

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      <!-- <br>{{ formset.as_table }}<br> -->

      {% for question in questions %}<hr>

    <label for="question">{{ question }} [{{ question.id }}]</label>  
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>


  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ question.answer }}"/>
  </p> 

{% endfor %}
       <br><br><br><hr> <br><br><br>
    </table><br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="../../baseVisite/" class="btn btn-success">Retour</a></center>
  </form>
```

I don't know how to retrieve the answer in the answer field in the database if there is one.

My problem is this line in my template :

```
<input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ HERE }}"/>
```

I don't know what to put in value to retrieve the answer

Comment: What if a question have multiple replies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Question` object will have `reply_set` attribute with record set of all the objects of `Reply` linked with that question, over which you can iterate and display.

```
{% for reply in question.reply_set %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Of-course you will have to handle one question having multiple replies.